# Vim leader key not working most of time

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin

I am new to Vim and have a fairly simple vimrc, in which I remapped the leader key like this `let mapleader=","`.

However, when I pressed `<leader>+w` for the EasyMotion plugin, it sometimes work but for the most of the time it is not working. Even if I delete this line and use `\` as the leader key, the behavior is similar.

Any idea how I can get my leader key to work? I am stuck on this. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure it out myself using `gvim -u NONE`.

Comment: No worries. I'll try other configuration to validate that. Thanks!

Comment: Post your .vimrc please

Comment: sounds like you are not fast enough. Enter ":set timeoutlen=2000" (Only for testing ) and look if your leader "works" now. If this is the case you have to find a value which is good for you

Comment: According to https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion, the default leader has been changed to <Leader><Leader> to avoid conflicts with other plugins you may have installed. So I added `map <Leader> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)` in my .vimrc and now it is working fine. Thanks!